# Advice on loggin strategy - how to send logging info to multiple destinations based on type of exception

Tags: logging, exception, log4j, log4net

Im looking for an example log4net/log4j config which allows logging different types of errors to different destinations.

For example:

if service error happens (due to unavailability of some external service), I need the administrator of that service to be notified and possibly our developers or managers as well.

if internal error happens (due to malfunctioning of our app), I want the app developers to be notified (but not admins or managers), and provided enough info to solve that problem.

Please share your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example extension in the log4net download that shows how to add a custom trace level to log4net.

Have a look in extensions\net\1.0\log4net.Ext.Trace

You could create a custom level for SERVICE and a custom level for INTERNAL.

In you code you would use Log.SERVICE() and Log.INTERNAL()

Your configuration would be something like this:

```
<appender name="EmailAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="SERVICE" />
  </evaluator>

  <subject value="Error in the service" />
  <to value="service_admin@yourcompany.com" />
</appender>
<appender name="EmailAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="INTERNAL" />
  </evaluator>

  <subject value="Error in the internals" />
  <to value="internal_admin@yourcompany.com" />
</appender>
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer! I've seen the example and it seems like a lot of work.. im looking for a simpler solution. Maybe it's possible to achieve this with Filters? I could set string matching filters on the appenders and in my log messages use "SERVICE" and "INTERNAL" flags?